# How to remove linear fit between two variables?

Tags: python, regression, jupyter

I want to remove the correlation between two variables, X and Y, by removing the line of fit between them. My rustic codes are as follows:

```
X = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\folder\X.csv') 
X = pd.DataFrame(X,columns=['Year','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'])
X  X[X['Year'].between(1984,2020, inclusive="both")]

Y = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\folder\Y.csv') 
Y = pd.DataFrame(Y,columns=['Year','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'])
Y=Y[Y['Year'].between(1984,2020, inclusive="both")]
```

I want to transform Y into new_Y by removing its correlation from X. I am only interested in removing the correlation in 'Mar'. I am using jupyter notebook and I am quite new in python or any other programming language. Thanks in advance.

[This is the data. I used 1984-2020 only when I read the .csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t3cn50r3k1i2egv/Data.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Could you add an example of how the data looks like? In addition, are you interested in the subtracting the best fit line from on the variables? This in not really the best way to remove correlation.

Comment: 1. I do not know how to add data here. 
2. Yes, I want to subtract the data of Y from X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you added data is not very helpful, unfortunately, since I cannot copy and paste it. However, here is an example you can generalize from, I think. Let me know if you have any questions.

The correlated vector `y` was created using the method outlined in [this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141427/how-does-the-formula-for-generating-correlated-random-variables-work).

```
import numpy as np

# Generate two random vectors
x1 = np.random.rand(100)
x2 = np.random.rand(100)

# Generate another vector, linearly correlated with x1
corr_coef = 0.7
y = corr_coef * x1 + np.sqrt(1 - corr_coef ** 2) * x2 

p = np.polyfit(x1, y, 1)

# Remove the correlation with x1 by subracting the linear fit:
uncorr_y = y - np.polyval(p, x1)

# plot the original data with the fit
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x1, y,'.')
plt.plot(x1, np.polyval(p, x1), 'r-')
plt.xlabel('x1')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()

# Plot the uncorrelated data
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x1, uncorr_y ,'.')
plt.xlabel('x1')
plt.ylabel(r'$y_{uncorr}$')
plt.show()
```

Here is the a plot of the correlated an uncorrelated data:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your fast reply. I was just trying to figure my way in here. I added the link to the data.